# Automatically Run VBA Code when an Excel Workbook Opens

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code in I would like to run when the Excel workbook is opened.

I tried creating a public procedure in the sheet the code is supposed to run in:

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open 
    ' Some code here
End Sub
```

It does not run when the workbook opens.

It is supposed to create a combobox in one of the cells and then fill it with information from the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that the code is in the `ThisWorkbook` scope of the VBA editor and **not** in a module or worksheet:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "Autorun works!"
    'your code here
End Sub
```

And make sure that your [macros are enabled](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6).

For details also see Microsoft's documentation: [Automatically run a macro when opening a workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automatically-run-a-macro-when-opening-a-workbook-1e55959b-e077-4c88-a696-c3017600db44?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: Hi, My macros are enable and the Option Explicit line was added, Although changing the declaration from Public to Private does not work as now when I run the program the WorkBook_Open procedure doesn't show up in the window

Comment: Where did you place the code? In `ThisWorkbook` or in a module? Test it with a MsgBox like I showed above. If macros are enabled this *must* work.

Comment: Hi, In this WorkBook, Let me try putting it in the VBA Editor

Comment: @Bonang No it **must** be in `ThisWorkbook` to make it work. See the Microsoft documentation link I gave in my answer. Follow it step by step.

Comment: @Bonang Just for my interest: What was the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Pᴇʜ's answer, you can also use the following procedure in standard module:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    '// Your code here...
End Sub
```

Comment: You should not use the `Auto_Open` event as this is for backwards compatibility only and will probably removed in future versions.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I do not insist - I just provided an alternative 

Comment: Of course, nothing wrong with suggesting an alternative. I just thought it might be worth to mention that if you use it you bet on an old horse.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yeah... But this horse is more than 20 years and continue to work. As we say, "Old horse won't cause harm to furrow" 

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an event procedure that activates when you open a book. Go to **thisworkbook** in the VBA editor and choose workbook open procedure from the drop down list above the coding window, or you can type manually:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
```