# How can i show a VBA UserForm automatically when Excel workbook opens?

Tags: excel, vba, project, program-entry-point, userform

I have one userform `sira_main` in the workbook `sira.xlsm` that not opens automatically upon opening the workbook.

I put this code into GENERAL and DECLARATIONS of the main sheet but doesn't work:

> Call sira_main.Show

[VBA project window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WODA5.png)

Please help me!.

Comment: Welcomee to SO! Please read [ask] then improve question! E.g. **never** show code as image! **Always** show code as text [formated as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) as we want to copy and paste it!. Also the `Call`statement is obsolete, a simple `sira_main.Show`is sufficent.

Comment: This post contains implicitly several questions. Also the code shown in the image cannot run at all as it will not compile based on the posted screenshot. Please also re-phrase your post to a question because _but doesn't work_ is not a question and also not helpful. For possible answers look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53425919/automatically-run-vba-code-when-an-excel-workbook-opens and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53544947/run-macro-when-open-workbook and https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2011/06/03/show-userform-when-excel-file-opens/

Answer (score 2):

Call it when workbook open event happens (in `ThisWorkbook`):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call sira_main.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: [Call statement](https://rubberduckvba.com/Features/FeatureItem/ObsoleteCallStatement?example=1) is obsolete, a simple `sira_main.Show`is sufficent.

Comment: And good practice would be to create an instance of the form an show that

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Got it! I can't remember if I once knew that `call` is obsolete. I just code following what I learnt from the book (and there is `call` in the example code).

Comment: @chrisneilsen by far more important, but without a proper link, users won't know why not to use [UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)!

Comment: @chrisneilsen Since I've only created small VBA projects to help my own work, haven't code that carefully. And this is the first time I know `new` in VBA. I'll dig into that.